I would like to know the original source (English translation) of Vashishta neutralizing Vishwamitras attacks with a Brahmadanda
I am interested in the Brahmadanda - what does it stand for? What does it symbolize? Who made it? How may it have looked?

I) Your first question I am interested in the Brahmadanda - what does it stand for? What does it symbolize? Who made it? How may it have looked?
In Hindu mythology, the Brahmadandam(ब्रह्मदंडम्) is a weapon created by Brahma that can absorb any attack and nullify the effects of divine weapons. The Brahmadanda is a rod and is also known as Meru-danda. The powers of the Brahmadanda depend on the owner, who must be an ascetic. The Rishi/Sage who holds the Brahmadanda must perform tapasya to infuse the staff with enough power to absorb the destructive force of other astras. Therefore, its powers are dependent on its owner. For example:

When Vishvāmitra unleashed the Brahmāstram(ब्रह्मास्त्रम्) onto Vasishtha,
it was Vasishtha's Brahmadandam(ब्रह्मदंडम्) that protected him.

Definition: The Brahmadanda is defined in the Dhanurveda-saṃhitā [an ancient India Science], which is a list of 117 weapons and is said to have been composed by the Maharishi Vasiṣṭha. An image of Brahmadanda is shown: 
II) Your second and final question I would like to know the original source (English translation) of Vashishta neutralizing Vishwāmitra's attacks with a Brahmadanda.
The story of legend Maharishi Vishvāmitra has been narrated in Vālmiki Rāmāyana, Bāla Kānda [Chapters: 51-56] summarized as follows:

Vishvāmitra tries to abduct Kāmadhenu from Maharishi Vashishta
but Vashishta persistently refuses Vishvamitra's bargains and
barters [Chapter-53].

The seizure of Kāmadhenu, the Sacred Cow, causes anxiety in
her and she urges Vashishta to counteract the atrocity of
Vishvamitra. Agreeing to her, the sage asks the Cow to create a
force that can subdue the forces of Vishvamitra. Accordingly, that
Cow generates newer forces and a war ensue [Chapter-54].

Vishvamitra ruins Vashishta's hermitage on acquiring astras
at the grace of God Shiva by practising a paramount ascesis
[Chapter-55].

Vashishta nullifies Vishvamitra's Astras(अस्त्र/Missile) just by his
Brahmadanda(ब्रह्मदंडम्). All astras are defused when Vashishta consumed
them. Vishvamitra launches the highest missile, namely
Brahmashtra(ब्रह्मास्त्र), which too is consumed by Vashishta, whereby the body
of Vashishta becomes a Brahmashtra(Brahma missile) and starts to emit radiation.
Then, upon the prayer of gods and saints, Vashishta withdraws the
effect of that astras [Chapter-56].



Vishvamitra on seeing this concludes that
mere astras(missiles) are of no use and thus he embarks on a sublime ascesis in order to become Brahma Rishi(ब्रह्मऋषि)!

